# x-scroll bar obstructing hover box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have a page with elements that have a hover box appear either below or above them depending on whether they fits below the page. it works fine unless the x-scroll bar is visible in which case the box can still appear below the element even if the scroll bar is obstructing the box. to demonstrate this. you can visit this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sC34G/) and just slowly hover from the top to the bottom of the input, I think you'll see what I mean. It's just a small bug really, but I would like to fix it if anyone knows how. Thank you. Here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
 leftX=(e.pageX -($('#box').width()+20)) + "px";

if((e.pageY+($('#box').height() + 31)) < ($(window).scrollTop() + window.innerHeight)){
   topY = (e.pageY + 20) + "px";
}else{
   topY=e.pageY - $('#box').height() - 20 + "px";
}

  $('#box').css({'top':topY,'left':leftX});

});

$('input').mouseout(function(){
    $('#box').hide();
});

$('input').mouseover(function(){
    $('#box').show();
});
```

Comment: Did the new answer worked ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay: Try this: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sC34G/6/)**

First of all, you forgot to end the `p tag`, but I guessing that's just in the fiddle not your actual code.

Second I wasn't sure if you wanted the `pink box` to move as you `hover` from `right to left` on input box. So I made it `fixed length - hard coded`.

And here's what you can do:

**IN JS**

```
 $('#box').css({'top':topY,'left':'29px'});
```

And

```
 topY = (e.pageY + 24) + "px";
```

And

```
 topY=e.pageY - $('#box').height() - 24 + "px";
```

Now, In case you don't want it hard-coded, I changed the `leftX` variable calculation as follows:

```
 leftX=(e.pageX -($('#box').width()-120)) + "px";
```

Then use `leftX` as :

```
 $('#box').css({'top':topY,'left':leftX});
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle, but I'm still getting the same problem.the x-scroll still obstructs the hover box

Comment: What do you mean by obstructs ? I don't see it. Which browser are you using ?

Comment: when the box is behind the scroll bar, it should, never get to that point. it should move above the element before getting hidden by the scroll bar.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot ?

Comment: Just very slowly move the mouse from the top of the input to the bottom and observe that before it jumps to above the element, the bottom of the box is partially obstructed by the scroll bar

Comment: Okay: do this: `topY=e.pageY - $('#box').height() - 24 + "px";` And `topY = (e.pageY + 24) + "px";` Change from 20 to 24. I still can't find the issue though. Are you using any specific browser ? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sC34G/6/